# Dialog box before adding comment facebook fan page comment box

Tags: facebook, dialog, comments, facebook-page

I need to add a dialog box which will display few text before user can add comment on facebook fan page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly on facebook.

You must create an app that will add a comment on your page, and inside that app display the dialog box.

Otherwise, I'm pretty sure Facebook won't let you do that.

Comment: Bogdan Bucur Thank you for reply!!